# Pandas Rank Multiple Columns for huge dataset using Threadpool

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-multithreading

I need to rank each column of the dataframe. I'm currently using the below code:

```
for x in range(1,len(cols)):
    data[cols[x]] = data[cols[x]].rank(ascending=0)
```

This works for small dataset. I have more than 50,000 columns and 20,000 rows. Is there a way I can achieve faster with Threadpool. Tried the below code but it didn't work. It is returning empty set.

```
cols = rankDset.columns.tolist()

def rank_columns(c):
    rankDset[c] = rankDset[c].rank(ascending=0)

def parallelDataframe(df, func):

    pool = Pool(8)
    pool.map(func, cols)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()


parallelDataframe(rankDset, rank_columns)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to rank every column by using [**`pd.DataFrame.rank`**](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html):

```
df.rank()
```

From [Docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html)

> Compute numerical data ranks (1 through n) along axis.
>
> axis: {0 or ‘index’, 1 or ‘columns’}, default 0
>
> index to direct ranking

consider the dataframe `df`

```
np.random.seed([3,1415])
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
        A=np.random.choice(np.arange(10), 5, False),
        B=np.random.choice(np.arange(10), 5, False),
        C=np.random.choice(np.arange(10), 5, False),
        D=np.random.choice(np.arange(10), 5, False),
    ))

df

   A  B  C  D
0  9  1  6  0
1  4  3  8  2
2  5  5  9  6
3  1  9  7  1
4  7  4  3  9
```

Then ranking produces

```
df.rank()

     A    B    C    D
0  5.0  1.0  2.0  1.0
1  2.0  2.0  4.0  3.0
2  3.0  4.0  5.0  4.0
3  1.0  5.0  3.0  2.0
4  4.0  3.0  1.0  5.0
```